# You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0 in Mac

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to compile a ASP.NET Core RC2 Project in a Mac with ASP.NET Core RC2 installed. This is my project.json:

```
    {
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-TestCoreRC2-6a20d1d3-f55a-4683-a8ca-5f5fbff19ab4",

  "dependencies": {

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.20"
      }
    }   

  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "TestCoreRC2"
  }
}
```

This is the error:

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   process this request. Please review the following specific error
>   details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Generated Code
>
> Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the
>   compiler required type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found.
>   Are you missing a reference?
>       public class _Views_Home_Index_cshtml : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage Predefined type
>   'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported
>       public class _Views_Home_Index_cshtml : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage The type 'Object' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a bug? https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11908

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4818#issuecomment-224775503)

Asp.Net Core currently does not work well under Mono net451, but there is a chance that it might work.

Just follow the workaround instructions in the link provided.

Comment: I can't believe that... first time I try to create a project, and boom, error... What happers to Microsoft Team???

Comment: That is a good question. The answer is Steve Ballmer happened to them. See every time they ponder on whether there will be a backlash when they release crap, they think back to the days when good old Ballmer murdered entire .net projects. Then they realize that their crap does not even compare with what that guy Ballmer did and then proceed to release the rubbish. See Steve desensitized them to willingly betraying developers.

Comment: I am sorry but i did not understand the solution. Could you please summarize it here?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing similar issues of referencing mscorlib. Resolved it by adding `"Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1-rc2-24027"`. This package resolves dependencies with PCL still targeting mscorlib. More details are [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.netcore.portable.compatibility/)

**Edit**
Just now I saw you are targeting net451 on Mac. You will need to switch to "netcoreapp1.0": {} to support cross platform. Try making following changes to project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {  
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "platform"
},
//other dependencies
},
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {}
},
//Other configs
```

Comment: Where did you put this reference? Thanks!

Comment: Under dependencies in project.json. It solved the `mscorlib` error.

Comment: I can't switch to netcoreapp1.0 because I'm using libraries not ready to core yet (like PayPal). Thanks!

Comment: You can try the `import` statement to try to add libraries which are not yet built for rc2. Have a look at last paragraph [here](https://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/dnx-migration.html).